# SAP RFC module for getting measurement

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, sap-erp, saprfc

I have been using `MEASUREM_DOCUM_RFC_SINGLE_001` to update a measurement point in SAP through .Net 2.0, and this worked quite well. I would like to read the latest measurement point, but I am unable to find a RFC in the Function group `IMR0`.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about measurement points, but there seems to be a function module to read the documents (MEASUREM_DOCUM_RFC_SINGLE_002) if you know the keys. If there is no RFC module to get a list of $foo according to a set of selection criteria, you could always try RFC_READ_TABLE to get the keys directly from the database table. If you were programming in Java, I'd recommend some wrapper classes I've written - don't know whether a similar thing already exists for C#.